# Trouble with rendering the page after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
$.post(
    'url', {
    date: $('#date').val()
},
function (response) {
    $("#content").html(response);
});
```

So basically, I pass a date to my script and return a list of records. The problem I have is that if I pick a date more than 1 year ago, the page doesn't load. I assume it would take more time for my script to run and therefore it doesn't work. is there a way that I can wait for the ajax to complete before I render the page?

Comment: You are doing it right - waiting for the response and then loading content. The problem is something else. Try `alert($('#date').val())` before the post and see

Comment: *"is there a way that I can wait for the ajax to complete before I render the page?"* you're already doing that with the code you've posted, the success won't run until the ajax is successful.

Comment: Do you mean a string breaks the code? This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not a timeout?

Try using the following to debug more

```
$.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, request) { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function(data, textStatus, request) { alert(textStatus); })
.always(function(data, textStatus, request) { alert("finished"); });
```

Comment: ok I tried your code and for the date that is in 2013 or 2012, I got second success, finished. for the date that in 2011 or earlier, I got error and finished.

Comment: I think it might has something to do with my database.

Comment: ok so in the error one look at the request parameter and see the status code and text for more details. What server code you using?